# Upgrade to debian 9 but keep package from debian 8?

Tags: linux, debian, dotdeb, debian-stretch

We're using a custom repository to install a `full-http2` compliant patched version of `nginx` that is available for jessie.The repository is called dotdeb, and I can't find any reference to debian 9 strech.
 (http://packages.dotdeb.org/dists/)

**Can I upgrade from jessie to strech, while still referencing nginx from the dotdeb repository (jessie) ?** 
Or should all packages comes from equals debian version or higher ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. The idea of package repositories is that you can have multiple sources. To be certain, you can simulate the upgrade, you can get a list of all the changes, look through 'Upgraded' and 'Removed' - if your package isn't there you're fine.

```
apt-get --dry-run dist-upgrade
```

If you want to be really sure, you can put a hold on the package, which will stop it changing:

```
apt-mark hold <package-name>
```

Finally: I hope you're testing this on a dev/uat server before rolling out to production. If you do it, and it breaks on dev, no one will care, there's no risk. If you don't have a dev box, go buy a cheap pc, a raspberry pi will do, set it up like your prod environment and then do the upgrade, that's your best test.